# What is the need of templated special member function and assignment operator function?

Tags: c++11

Let's say we have std unique_ptr

```
constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;
constexpr unique_ptr( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;
(1) 
explicit unique_ptr( pointer p ) noexcept;
(2) 
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d1 ) noexcept;
(3) 
unique_ptr( pointer p, /* see below */ d2 ) noexcept;
(4) 
unique_ptr( unique_ptr&& u ) noexcept;
(5) 
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept; (6)
```

Example taken from cppreference.com
Why we need the templated constructor in case 6?

Same goes for operator functions

```
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ) noexcept;
(1) 
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr<U,E>&& r ) noexcept;
(2) 
unique_ptr& operator=( std::nullptr_t ) noexcept;
(3)
```

In the above, the 2nd function.
I have seen this in pair also. Is there any purpose?

Comment: Have you read the docs you mentioned?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr - there are several sentences there about what constructor #6 is for.

Comment: I don't clearly get the use cases

Answer (score 1):

This constructor:

```
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;
```

Allows transfer of ownership from an existing unique_ptr which has a different deleter.  It requires the "old" deleter be convertible to the "new" one by calling a constructor of the new deleter.

It's the same idea for this move assignment operator:

```
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr<U,E>&& r ) noexcept;
```

Neither of the above methods are commonly used in application code.  It's probably best to forget they exist at all, unless you do a lot of work with custom deleters.

Answer (score 0):

The most common use case is to pass ownership from a `std::unique_ptr<Derived>` to a `std::unique_ptr<Base>`.